# as3 Greensock LoaderMax memory

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap, loadermax

I have a bit trouble with LoaderMax memory occupy, i have a queue, and i am keep loading images depend on user's action. if they click load more and it keep load, but i would like to clean the memory which been occupied by the previous queue (i have remove all the children been added by the loading previously). is there a way i can do it?

the behavior like this.

> load
>     (load the page 1)
>   load
>     (load the page 2 and clean the page 1)

```
queue = new LoaderMax({name:"mainQueue", autoDispose :'true'});
```

**

> A very quick question, everything in the queue (images). Do they all
>   cache in the browser?

**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{ autoDispose:true }` will not unload content, only call the `LoaderMax` instances dispose method automatically.

You can either call `queue.unload()` or `queue.dispose(true)` to remove your loaded content.

Also make sure you have removed any listeners from the children you added to the display to ensure they are garbage collected.

[LoaderMax Documentation](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/loading/LoaderMax.html)

To answer your quick question: depends on the browsers settings but probably. LoaderMax has cache-busting options if you are worried about that.